# How to run a Chrome Extension only when the clock hits a specific time

Tags: javascript

```
var timeToJoin = '18:13';
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();


var SST = 'https://meet.google.com/rnc-akmx-ubk';

if (time == timeToJoin) {
    joinClass();
}

function joinClass() {
    location.href = SST;
    setTimeout(offMicVideo, 10000);
}

function offMicVideo() {
    var video = document.getElementsByClassName('I5fjHe');
    var mic = document.getElementsByClassName('oTVIqe');

    for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
        video[i].click();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < mic.length; i++) {
        mic[i].click();
    }
}
```

This is my javascript code, what it simply does is open google when the correct time comes and join my online class. A small problem is in this line if

```
(time == timeToJoin) {
    joinClass();
}
```

Whats happening here is the condition I have given is `true` for a minute and therefore the bot keeps try to join a class for one minute, it opens the link then again opens the same link till the condition becomes false.

I tried my best to solve this problem but don't know why none of them worked.

Comment: Well, what did you try?

Comment: You are simply comparing two strings `"18:13" == "18:14"` for example... You need to compare real time, but for which amount of time does the link should be accessible?

Comment: This code is a chrome extension

Comment: I tried to this condition


var value = false ;

if(time == timeToJoin && value = =false ){
value = true ;
......

Comment: You need to use a state variable like `let joined = false;`. Then simply set it to true when you join, and check if it's false before joining.

Comment: If i would compare real time then also same problem will occur

Comment: I try to add a state variable it does not done the job

Comment: var joined = false ; 

if (time == timeToJoin && joined == false) {
    joined = true ; 
    joinClass();
}

I made the following changes to my code but its still not working

Comment: var joined = false ; 

if (time == timeToJoin && joined == false) {
    joined = true ; 
    joinClass();
}



I made the following changes to my code but its still not working

Comment: As your question is specific to Chrome extension development, consider tagging your question with `google-chrome-extension`, as then you will better target the audience of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the script starts from scratch each time, you'll need to persist whether the videoclass was joined in a previous run. You can use Chrome's [storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) for that. The documentation explains:

> You must declare the "storage" permission in the extension manifest to use the storage API. For example:
>
> ```
>   {
>     "name": "My extension",
>     ...
>     "permissions": [
>       "storage"
>     ],
>     ...
>   }
> ```
>
> To store user data for your extension, you can use either `storage.sync` [...] of `storage.local`:
>
> ```
>   chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
>     console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
>   });
>
>   chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
>     console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
>   });
> ```

So once you have the manifest adapted, change the following part of your code:

```
if (time == timeToJoin) {
    joinClass();
}
```

...to this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({ classStarted: false }, function({classStarted}) {
   if ((time === timeToJoin) === classStarted) return; // nothing to do
   if (!classStarted) {
     // Persist the fact that we start the class, and call joinClass once it is persisted
     chrome.storage.sync.set({ classStarted: true }, joinClass); 
   } else { 
     // At least one minute elapsed, so we can clean up the persisted value now...
     chrome.storage.sync.remove("classStarted"); 
   }
});
```